# MongoDB size in bytes of different types

Tags: mongodb, nosql, bson

In MongoDB, we have different types in a BSON document (NumberDecimal, int32, int64, String).

What is the size in bytes of NumberDecimal and the integer types specifically?

Answer (score 0):

A complete spec is available in the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html).

NumberDecimal is a 128-bit decimal floating point

Integer/Number is a 64-bit binary floating point